# Addressing x and y in aes by variable number

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to draw a scatterplot with addressing variables by their column numbers instead of names, i.e. instead of `ggplot(dat, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2))` I need something like `ggplot(dat, aes(x=dat[,1], y=dat[,2]))`. (I say 'something' because the latter doesn't work).

Here is my code:

```
showplot1<-function(indata, inx, iny){
  dat<-indata
  print(nrow(dat)); # this is just to show that object 'dat' is defined
  p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=dat[,inx], y=dat[,iny]))
  p + geom_point(size=4, alpha = 0.5)
}

testdata<-data.frame(v1=rnorm(100), v2=rnorm(100), v3=rnorm(100), v4=rnorm(100), v5=rnorm(100))
showplot1(indata=testdata, inx=2, iny=3)
```

> ```
> # Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'dat' not found
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A variation on @Shadow's answer using new features from `ggplot2 V3.0.0` :

```
showplot <- function(indata, inx, iny){
  nms <- names(indata)
  x <- nms[inx]
  y <- nms[iny]
  p <- ggplot(indata, aes(x = !!ensym(x), y = !!ensym(y)))
  p + geom_point(size=4, alpha = 0.5)
}   

testdata <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(100), v2=rnorm(100), v3=rnorm(100), v4=rnorm(100), v5=rnorm(100))
names(testdata) <- c("a-b", "c-d", "e-f", "g-h", "i-j")
showplot(indata=testdata, inx=2, iny=3)
```

`ensym` creates a symbol from the string contained in a variable (so we first have to create those variables at the start of the function), then `!!` unquotes it, which means it will work as if you had fed the function raw names.

`!!` works only in the context of functions designed to support it, usually tidyverse functions, else it just means "not not" (similar to `as.logical`)..

Comment: Thank you Antoine! If you will have some time, maybe you could add just couple words explaining how this works? (for other not-so-advanced users like myself) If not, here's my understanding: `!!` operator - pronounced '_bang-bang'_ - unquotes names previously quoted by `ensym()`, it's part of _quasiquotation_ which is described in more details, for example, [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html). (I think it's worth explaining because it took me quite some time to figure out; googling '!!' obviously doesn't work.)

Answer (score 26):

Your problem is that `aes` doesn't know your function's environment and it only looks within `global environment`. So, the variable `dat` declared within the function is *not visible* to `ggplot2`'s `aes` function *unless you pass it explicitly* as:

```
showplot1<-function(indata, inx, iny) {
    dat <- indata
    p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=dat[,inx], y=dat[,iny]), environment = environment())
    p <- p + geom_point(size=4, alpha = 0.5)
    print(p)
}
```

Note the argument `environment = environment()` inside the `ggplot()` command. It should work now.

Comment: yes, I suspected that it was the problem of scope, now it's clear, and I like this solution even more. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I strongly suggest using `aes_q` instead of passing vectors to `aes` (@Arun's answer). It may look a bit more complicated, but it is more flexible, when e.g. updating the data.

```
showplot1 <- function(indata, inx, iny){
  p <- ggplot(indata, 
              aes_q(x = as.name(names(indata)[inx]), 
                    y = as.name(names(indata)[iny])))
  p + geom_point(size=4, alpha = 0.5)
}
```

And here's the reason why it is preferable:

```
# test data (using non-standard names)
testdata<-data.frame(v1=rnorm(100), v2=rnorm(100), v3=rnorm(100), v4=rnorm(100), v5=rnorm(100))
names(testdata) <- c("a-b", "c-d", "e-f", "g-h", "i-j")
testdata2 <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(100), v2=rnorm(100), v3=rnorm(100), v4=rnorm(100), v5=rnorm(100))
names(testdata2) <- c("a-b", "c-d", "e-f", "g-h", "i-j")

# works
showplot1(indata=testdata, inx=2, iny=3)
# this update works in the aes_q version
showplot1(indata=testdata, inx=2, iny=3) %+% testdata2
```

---

**Note:** As of *ggplot2 v2.0.0* `aes_q()` has been replaced with `aes_()` to be consistent with SE versions of NSE functions in other packages.

Comment: indeed, your solution looks more flexible, I also like that it makes correct axes titles... Thanks!

Comment: As of ggplot2 v2.0.0: aes_q() has been replaced with aes_() to be consistent with SE versions of NSE functions in other packages https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md#deprecated-features

Comment: This answer worked well for me too, thank you. I must say, ggplot doesn't seem to be designed for people who work with very large numbers of quantities (rows in the data frame).

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
showplot1 <- function(indata, inx, iny) {
    x <- names(indata)[inx] 
    y <- names(indata)[iny] 
    p <- ggplot(indata, aes_string(x = x, y = y))
    p + geom_point(size=4, alpha = 0.5)
}
```

Edited to show what's happening - aes_string uses quoted arguments, names gets them using your numbers.

Comment: sorry @alexwhan, it's not very clear for me - could you explain a little bit more? Thanks!

Comment: First version didn't actually answer your question - try the edit

Comment: @alexwhan, please check your answers before posting. I've made an edit each to both of your answers.

Comment: the very last version works for this example (the previous edit, with `aes` instead of `aes_string`, did not work). 
Although it doesn't work for my real data because my table have hyphens in the names which makes error on processing: for example, if the column was called `someName-one`, I get an error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'someName' not found`. At the same time, this names' bug does not make any problem when I use your solution with `environment()`, so it is still preferable for me.

Comment: @VasilyA, the very last version is my edit. Yes, I thought of this problem with unusual names. But since you dint post here,  I dint think it was your case. I'm glad you wrote it here, it'll help others.

Comment: @Arun - you're right, I started answering then my battery went flat... Had to follow up on phone without R...

Comment: @VasilyA, make sure to accept Arun's answer (and upvote it) since it solved your problem!

Comment: I did accept his answer already :) But I am grateful to your answer as well because it helped me to understand better some aspects of using aes.

Answer (score 3):

The `aes_()` and `aes_quote()` approaches are now soft deprecated. An easy way that is also consistent with quasiquotation is to call the column names via `.data[[col_name]]`. You can easily extract these based on position. For example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

showplot1<-function(indata, inx, iny){
  dat<-indata
  col_names <- names(indata)
  col_name_x <- col_names[[inx]]
  col_name_y <- col_names[[iny]]
  
  print(nrow(dat)); # this is just to show that object 'dat' is defined
  p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=.data[[col_name_x]], y=.data[[col_name_y]]))
  p + geom_point(size=4, alpha = 0.5)
}

testdata<-data.frame(v1=rnorm(100), v2=rnorm(100), v3=rnorm(100), v4=rnorm(100), v5=rnorm(100))
showplot1(indata=testdata, inx=2, iny=3)
#> [1] 100
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, I think it's safer to use column names instead of indices because column positions within a data frame can be changed causing unexpected results.

The `plot_duo` function below (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50930640/786542)) can use input either as strings or bare column names

```r
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

theme_set(theme_classic(base_size = 14))
set.seed(123456)
testdata <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(100), v2 = rnorm(100), v3 = rnorm(100), 
                       v4 = rnorm(100), v5 = rnorm(100))

plot_duo <- function(df, plot_var_x, plot_var_y) {

  # check if input is character or bare column name to 
  # use ensym() or enquo() accordingly
  if (is.character(plot_var_x)) {
    print('character column names supplied, use ensym()')
    plot_var_x <- ensym(plot_var_x)
  } else {
    print('bare column names supplied, use enquo()')
    plot_var_x <- enquo(plot_var_x)
  }

  if (is.character(plot_var_y)) {
    plot_var_y <- ensym(plot_var_y)
  } else {
    plot_var_y <- enquo(plot_var_y)
  }

  # unquote the variables using !! (bang bang) so ggplot can evaluate them
  pts_plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x = !! plot_var_x, y = !! plot_var_y)) + 
    geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.5)

  return(pts_plt)
}
```

Apply `plot_duo` function across columns using `purrr::map()`

```r
### use character column names
plot_vars1 <- names(testdata)
plt1 <- plot_vars1 %>% purrr::map(., ~ plot_duo(testdata, .x, "v1"))
#> [1] "character column names supplied, use ensym()"
#> [1] "character column names supplied, use ensym()"
#> [1] "character column names supplied, use ensym()"
#> [1] "character column names supplied, use ensym()"
#> [1] "character column names supplied, use ensym()"

str(plt1, max.level = 1)
#> List of 5
#>  $ :List of 9
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"
#>  $ :List of 9
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"
#>  $ :List of 9
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"
#>  $ :List of 9
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"
#>  $ :List of 9
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"

# test plot
plt1[[3]]
```

[image]

```r
### use bare column names
# Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834499/
plot_vars2 <- rlang::exprs(v2, v3, v4)
plt2 <- plot_vars2 %>% purrr::map(., ~ plot_duo(testdata, .x, rlang::expr(v1)))
#> [1] "bare column names supplied, use enquo()"
#> [1] "bare column names supplied, use enquo()"
#> [1] "bare column names supplied, use enquo()"

str(plt2, max.level = 1)
#> List of 3
#>  $ :List of 9
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"
#>  $ :List of 9
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"
#>  $ :List of 9
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"

plt1[[2]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As a supplement to @moodymudskipper's answer, if you want to use it in a `magrittr` pipe, you can use

```
testdata %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=!!sym(names(.)[2]), y=!!sym(names(.)[3]))) +
    geom_point(size=4, alpha = 0.5)
```

Also, if you want to use `aes` in a specific layer only, you can use

```
testdata %>% 
    {ggplot(., aes(x=!!sym(names(.)[2]))) +
    geom_point(aes(y=!!sym(names(.)[3])), size=4, alpha = 0.5)}
```

Certainly, you can wrap it into a function if you need:

```
showplot <- function(indata, inx, iny){
    indata %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x=!!sym(names(.)[inx]), y=!!sym(names(.)[iny]))) +
        geom_point(size=4, alpha = 0.5)
}
```

Although this would actually lose the point of using a pipe

Answer (score 0):

provisional solution I found for the moment:

```
showplot1<-function(indata, inx, iny){
  dat<-data.frame(myX=indata[,inx], myY=indata[,iny])
  print(nrow(dat)); # this is just to show that object 'dat' is defined
  p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=myX, y=myY))
  p + geom_point(size=4, alpha = 0.5)
}
```

But I don't really like it because in my real code, I need other columns from `indata` and here I will have to define all of them explicitly in `dat<-`...