# Duplicate commands in different ggplot2 plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, dry

This seems like an issue many people would face, along the lines of the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle. I couldn't find the answer anywhere, perhaps I've been searching for the wrong terms, which means my question title probably isn't very good. If people have better suggestions of how to title the question that would be appreciated.

I have several `ggplot2` plots, and they all have some commands in common, as well as other commands that vary too much, so it is not worthwhile writing them altogether as a loop/function.

How can I include the common commands in a neat, one-liner?

An example would probably explain more clearly:

```
common.lines <- "theme_bw() +
                geom_point(size = 2) +
                stat_smooth(method = lm, alpha = 0.6) +
                ylab("Height")"

my.plot <- ggplot(data = my_df, aes(x = "Length", y = "Height")) +
             common.lines

jim.plot <- ggplot(data = jim_df, aes(x = "Width", y = "Height")) +
              common.lines
```

My question is, how do I construct `common.lines`? Making a string like the above doesn't work. I also tried making a vector and then `paste`ing with `+` as a separator.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: Even less redundancy if you make a function like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458526/r-pass-variable-column-names-to-ggplot2/15458593#15458593)

Comment: @Henrik thanks, I was aware of that, and I can do that sometimes to some degree, but like I said sometimes all the variation cannot be accounted for in a function form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could put the commands in a list.

```
my_df <- data.frame(Length=rnorm(100, 1:100), Height=rnorm(100, 1:100))
jim_df <- data.frame(Width=rnorm(100, sin(seq(1,4*pi,len=100))),
                     Height=rnorm(100, 1:100))
common.lines <- list(theme_bw(), geom_point(size = 2), 
                     stat_smooth(method = lm, alpha = 0.6), ylab("Special Label"))

my.plot <- ggplot(data = my_df, aes(Length, Height)) + common.lines
jim.plot <- ggplot(data = jim_df, aes(Width, Height)) + common.lines
jim.plot
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Now I wonder if there is a better title for this question so that others kind find it by searching for the relevant terms...