# Variable column names in the pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code:

```
install.packages('tidyverse')
library(tidyverse)
x <- 1:10
y <- x^2
df <- data.frame(first_column = x, second_column = y)
tibble <- as_tibble(df)

tibble %>% 
  filter(second_column != 16) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = first_column, y = second_column)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Now I would like to create the following function

```
test <- function(colname) {
  tibble %>% 
    filter(colname != 16) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = first_column, y = colname)) + 
    geom_line()
}

test('second_column')
```

But running it creates a vertical line instead of the function. How can I make this function work?
Edit: My focus is on getting the pipe to work, not ggplot.

Comment: Try using `aes_string(x = "first_column", y = colname)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R pass variable column indices to ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458526/r-pass-variable-column-indices-to-ggplot2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Addressing x and y in aes by variable number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323269/addressing-x-and-y-in-aes-by-variable-number)

Comment: aes_string works for ggplot, but my problem of variable column names in the pipe remanes.

Comment: Subset by name-of-column is easy using base R: `tibble[tibble[[colname]] != 16,]`

Comment: Note if the focus is on getting the filter to work then construct an example that works without needing `ggplot2`, then people without `ggplot2` installed can also help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass character strings for variable names, you have to use the *standard evaluation* version of each function. It is `aes_string` for `aes`, and `filter_` for `filter`. See the [NSE vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) for more details.

Your function could look like:

```
test <- function(colname) {
  tibble %>% 
    filter_(.dots= paste0(colname, "!= 16")) %>%
    ggplot(aes_string(x = "first_column", y = colname)) + 
    geom_line()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it. You forgot _ after filter btw.

Comment: Corrected, tanks !